# Facebook Messenger Virus on Android

Tags: security, malware, facebook, antivirus

I received a message from a friend on facebook

The message said "this video is yours 'mt name'" with a shocked emoji face and my profile picture below.

I was daft enough to click the link and then noticed that it did not take me to youtube, instead it went through a number of URL redirects, I then instantly closed the app.

I have searched online and found out about the "Facebook Messenger Virus" and this appears to be it.

Whilst searching, all removal details are aimed at Windows desktop computers.

I clicked the link from my android phone and am keen to find out if:

a) the malware affects android

and

B) if so, how to get rid

I have scanned with Norton Security, Malwarebytes and lookout and all say I am virus free but I would like to make sure that there is nothing else I should do?

any help would be great

Comment: Firstly Android is not affected by Virus. Next, added *malware* tag to your question. Click on that and read the tag wiki for help. You will find a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

No, It won't affect your phone because it is supposed to work on a windows OS and Android is completely different from it. If such thing was possible, everyone would have been broke till now.